# mysql : find upper case Alphabets in like clause

Tags: mysql

Need suggestion regarding  finding all testimonial List contains link like http://www.example.com/**UPPER CASE Letter**

```
select *  from testimonial3 where detail_text like '%http://www.example.com/Hind-global'
select *  from testimonial3 where detail_text like '%http://www.example.com/Apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *  FROM testimonial3 WHERE detail_text REGEXP BINARY 'http://www.example.com/[A-Z]{1}';
```